# PC and Mac can't see each other in network; Time Capsule transfers are slow

Tags: windows-7, macos, wireless-networking, time-capsule

I have troubles connecting from Mac to PC and vice versa. I have the following setup:

- **Router**
- **LAN:** Time Capsule (10.0.1.1)
- **Wireless:**

  - Mac OS 10.8 (10.0.1.2)
  - PC Windows 7 (10.0.1.5)

Here are the problems I experience:

- The Mac works perfectly connecting to the Time Capsule but PC can't copy large files from the Time Capsule – only small files. Also, its connection is slow.
- From the PC I can't see the Mac and vice versa, although they are on the same `WORKGROUP`.
- If I run a LAN cable to the Time Capsule from the PC it works perfectly – probably a Wireless card problem with the PC? I have an ***SMC - EZ Connect N - SMCWPCI-N2***.

Comment: What speed? 802.11a/b/g/n? Wireless can be fussy, so you may be on the right track.

Comment: Both are 802.11 n all are on the same room.